# Listing all directories, sub directories and files starting from the root

Tags: php, file-system

I have to deploy this code that will list all the directories, sub directories and files in it starting from the root. The code works but I am not sure if this is the correct way to list. It should not fail, though.

Also, in despite not allowing directories with the name `.` and `..`, they get printed. Why is that?

```
<?php

# Snippet that lists all the directories,sub directories and files under that directory
# recursive function

function directory_f_lister($root) {
    $dir_list = scandir($root);
    for($var=0;$var<count($dir_list);$var++) {
        if(is_readable($root.$dir_list[$var])) {
            if(is_dir($root.$dir_list[$var])) {
                if($dir_list[$var] === "." || $dir_list[$var] === "..") continue;
                echo "<h3>Name of directory $dir_list[$var]</h3>";
                echo "<br />";
                $dh = opendir($root.$dir_list[$var]);
                while(($name = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                    if(is_dir($root.$dir_list[$var].$name)) {
                        if($dir_list[$var] === "." || $dir_list[$var] === "..") continue;
                        echo "Name of directory : <strong> $name </strong>";
                        echo "<br />";
                        directory_f_lister($root.$dir_list[$var].$name);
                    }else {
                        echo $name;
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

directory_f_lister(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

well `.` and  `..` are not directories, thats are navigationpoints of directories, . means go inside a root directory, .. means go one folder back,

you might noticed this already in includes like `include ../../../foo/bar.php`

also instead of scandir and readdir php has classes for this purpose [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) or [FileSystemIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php)

And if you wish to create reusable methods, dont do output there, instead return an array of folders/files something like

```
$directories = scanDirectories($rootDirectory); //create output array
foreach($directories as $directory){
    echo $directory.'<br/>';  
}
```

this allowes you to modify the output without editing the sourcecode, you could also wrap the output within a function e.g. `viewDirectories` and reuse it on different places.

here is a small Example

```
    ini_set('html_errors', 'On');

function scanDirectory($path) {
    $path = realpath($path);

     return  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

}

foreach(scanDirectory('./') as $name=> $object){

    echo $name.'<br/>';
}
```

About your question:

```
$root.$dir_list[$var].$name //this is your directory name
```

but youre checking if this name is . and ..

```
$dir_list[$var]
```

so its never becomes true

Answer (score 1):

1. If you invert your if condition and continue with next loop entry then you can reduce your level of nesting.
2. You will currently miss all files in the first `$root` (due do the outer `is_dir` condition).
3. You should be able move the recursion further to the top. The shorted algorithm for recursively listing directories goes like this (pseudo code):

   ```
   func list(root)
       print "Directory: " + root
       foreach (entry in contentof(root))
           if (entry is directory)
               list(entry)
           else
               print "File: " + entry
   ```

   In your code that could look something like this:

   ```
   function directory_f_lister($root)
   {
        echo "<h3>Name of directory: $root</h3>";
        echo "<br>";
        for (scandir($root) as $current)
        {
            $currentFullPath = $root.$current;
            if (!is_readable($currentFullPath) || $current == "." || $current == "..")
                continue;
            if (is_dir($currentFullPath))
            {
                list($currentFullPath);
            }
            else
            {
                echo $current;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Your approach intermingles the iteration of the structure (filesystem) with the actions of what to do for each item (printing). A better way would be to simply use the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to iterate over the filesystem and print each item.